# spring mvc @pathvariable not working with url file extension

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

i am facing an issue while invoking spring mvc method which has pathvariable

```
@RequestMapping(value="/retrieveData/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ModelAndView retrieveData(@PathVariable  Long userId , HttpSession session) {
```

i have web.xml servlet mapping as below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in my jsp , i have my javascript

```
    document.getElementById("form1").action = "retrieveData.html/2";
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

so my question is, will path variable works with url file extension in my case i have *.html , which i eventually want my servlet to map /retrieveData/{userId}

while submitting the page i am getting HTTP Status 400 error. help needed

EDIT:- i have ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean configure in my spring context

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <value>
            json=application/json
            xml=application/xml
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: `value="/retrieveData.html/{userId}"`?

Comment: it doesnt work, since *.html will be resolved to plain actions

Comment: Why? Where did you specified it? Did you use a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` with `mediaTypes`?

Comment: i have used ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean, i have edited my question too

Comment: try: `retrieveData/2.html` as url...I Spring should expect a url ends with `.html` so it just ignore it when it does the mapping...but to point to that url you have to include the `.html` at the end to let the application server call the spring servlet and then spring get the rest of url

Comment: @rascio, it works like charm now.. but is this right way to handle it? is there better way to handle it

Comment: It is a right way to handle it, but remember that **all** the urls managed from Spring have to ends with `.html` with that configuration so if you are planning to create some REST resource in JSON or XML also the URLs for them have to ends with `.html` to be managed from that spring application, and it is wrong (or at least they will be like `/resource/3.html?format=xml`...very ugly!)